# In Vim, how can I split edit a file on a server?

Tags: vim, split

With vim I can do:

```
gvim --servername things --remote-silent \temp\foo1.txt
```

And if I don't have a GVim with that servername it will create a new one. If I then execute this command:

```
gvim --servername things --remote-silent \temp\foo2.txt
```

I will then be editing `foo2.txt`.

What I want is to be able to split edit. Basically I want to be able to execute a command as many times as I want to send several different files to the same window in a new buffer for each new file - I've got Visual Studio setup to be able to launch the current file in a GVim instance, but it will launch a new instance every time, and I'd like it to just keep feeding files to the same instance.

From [these docs](http://wiki.arl.wustl.edu/~fredk/Courses/Docs/vim/remote.html), it says I can do `--remote-silent [+{cmd}] {file}`, so I've tried adding `"+split"`, but that ends  out opening two more buffers.

```
gvim --servername things --remote-silent "+split \temp\foo2.txt" \temp\foo2.txt
```

What is the command that I need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, there's `--remote-silent` and `--remote-tab-silent`, but no `--remote-split-silent`.

You have to send the `:split` as a Vim command:

```
gvim --servername things --remote-send "<C-\><C-n>:split \temp\foo2.txt<CR>"
```

As Vim interprets the characters as typed, you need to include the *special keys* like `<CR>` to conclude the command. `<C-\><C-n>` is a Vim command that goes to normal mode from any current mode.

Comment: This one doesn't quite do what I need, because I'd have to have two separate commands - one for the initial file, and then one for everything after that.

Comment: And for me, I get `E247` with `--remote-send` when the Vim instance doesn't exist yet. However, you can use that error in the wrapper script that you probably have to fallback to the initial command with `--remote-silent` then.

Comment: This works well enough, I suppose - I've got one command that opens the the server initially, and then another that will send the new file to.